# How to give Team City access to a GitHub Organisation's Private Repositories?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, teamcity

My organisation is using GitHub for source control - all repos are private.

We also have an internal server running Team City for CI.

What is the best way to allow TC to pull down changes from GitHub?

The only solution I can think of is to setup a new GitHub user and make the user a member of the organisation. Seems a bit long winded. I could also use my credentials, but that's a straight up hack.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I used a group email address to create a new user account on GitHub.

I also created a new Team on GitHub with *Read & Write* access to the projects managed in TeamCity, and added the new user to that Team.

I could have just specified *Read* access but I am using the Labelling feature of TeamCity that adds a Tag to the GitHub repository on each successful build, which therefore requires *Write* Access.